# How to make my explosion summoning code work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i'm making a game where the main mechanic is rocket jumping (Firing a rocket at your feet and the force of the explosion pushing you (like TF2)) and i can't get the explosion to summon only once AND it summons in the wrong place :/

I have tried adding waits into the if statement and stumbled upon what i am currently using. This in theory should work but doesn't.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Public changable things
    public float speed = 20.0f;
    public float life = 5.0f;
    public bool canRunProgress = true;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public GameObject Explosion;
    public Transform rocket;
    public Rigidbody rb;


    // If the object is alive for more than 5 seconds it dissapears.
    void Start()
    {
        Invoke("Kill", life);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //if the object isn't tounching the ground and is able to run it's process
        if (isGrounded == false && canRunProgress)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            canRunProgress = true;
        }
        //if the object IS touching the ground it then makes the above process unable to work and then begins the kill routine
        else if(isGrounded == true)
        {
            canRunProgress = false;
            StartCoroutine(Kill());
        }
        //detects if tounching ground
        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            {
                isGrounded = true;
            }
        }
        //detects if tounching ground
        void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            {
                isGrounded = false;
            }
        }
        //kill routine - explosion is summoned and explodes 2 seconds later it then destroys the rocket.
        IEnumerator Kill()
        {
            GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Explosion, transform); // also this needs to have the explosion be summoned in the middel of the rocket.
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

It should (when the rocket is summoned into the game by the launcher) make the rocket fly forward then when it hits the ground (with the tag "ground") stop moving and summon an explosion around it and 2 seconds later be destroyed. Currently it just bounces along the ground pathetically.

Any help would be appreciated. :3

Comment: Please fix the syntax error first.

Comment: Does code in `isGrounded == true` ever execute? Put a breakpoint or `Debug.Log` there and check. Also if your tags are `Ground` and `ground` then they are different tags and it will not work. And I see that your collision handlers are declared as *local* functions inside `Update`, thay should be methods in class, move them to outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

First, you got a syntax error : The OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionExit and Kill methods are inside the Update method... You should fix that first.

Then, for your code to work, i assume you have placed a Collider on the rocket, and a Collider on the ground. 
If the rocket is bouncing, it may be the cause of a Rigidbody. Indeed, the Rigidbody makes the objects collide and bouncing, thus not throwing the OnCollisionEnter. Try removing it if there is one on the rocket or ground.